# Is there a particular reason why Google drive need extra action to work?

Tags: android

Do i need to perform all those registration like getting SHA1 or AUTH2, if I need to upload a single file to Google drive from my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short**: Yes.

**Long**: All the requests you send to the Drive server are only executed if the provided authentication token is valid and it allows the action to be performed. To put an authentication token in the request you need to obtain it first. This can be done through the **OAuth2** flow only. And the OAuth2 authentication implementation by Google requires your app to be registered so that a token can be issued to that app. To register and identify your app you need the **SHA1** of the certificate the app was signed with.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It is pretty logical if all users use same drive, but why it is required if every user uses only its personal drive?

Comment: Do you mean accessing your own drive through your app, so that you  can store a file that's private for your app, or accessing the user's drive(account) where you'll store a file for the user?

Comment: Second. Where user acces his private drive through my app.

Comment: How would an app authenticate itself if those steps weren't required? Would then all apps be able to upload to the user's drive? The purpose of this oauth flow is to obtain the user's permission to access his/hers account.

Comment: my bad OAuth2 is required to protect users accaunt, but why my sha1 is required for that (I am not greed, just want reasons)?